# How to get rid of double quote from column's value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Here is the table, each column value is wrapped with double quotes (").

```
Name    Number      Address Phone1  Fax Value   Status
"Test"  "10000000"  "AB"    "5555"  "555"   "555"   "Active"
```

How to remove double quote from each column? I tried this for each column:-

```
UPDATE Table 
SET Name = substring(Name,1,len(Name)-1) 
where substring(Name,len(Name),1) = '"'
```

but looking for more reliable solution. This fails if any column has trailing white space

Comment: you could use TRIM() to get rid of trailing white spaces - i would do it they same way

Comment: Do you expect quotes in the actual data?

Comment: @Aaron thats correct it doesnt trim double-quotes but as per the last sentence in his question he concerns about the trailing white spaces...

Comment: Sorry, missed that. But there is no `TRIM()` in SQL Server. :-)

Comment: SQL Server has `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()`, just nest them for a full trim:
    `@result = LTRIM(RTRIM(@source))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Quotation Marks On All Rows in a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773275/remove-quotation-marks-on-all-rows-in-a-column)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just use REPLACE?

```
...
SET Name = REPLACE(Name,'"', '')
...
```

Comment: But it will replace all the quotes, not only wrapping the column value

Answer (score 11):

```
UPDATE Table
    SET Name = REPLACE(Name, '"', '')
    WHERE CHARINDEX('"', Name) <> 0
```

Comment: Your answer is also good.but then i have to write update tabl..... for each column... whereas without where clause i can update all the columns in one update statement.. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #t
(
   Name varchar(100)
)

insert into #t(Name)values('"deded"')
Select * from #t

update #t Set Name = Coalesce(REPLACE(Name, '"', ''), '')
Select * from #t
drop table #t
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Dirty, but it will work :-)
You could expand and write this as a store procedure taking in a table name, character you want to replace, character to replace with, Execute a String variable, etc...

```
DECLARE 
@TABLENAME VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @TABLENAME = 'Locations'

SELECT 'Update ' + @TABLENAME + ' set ' +  column_Name + ' = REPLACE(' + column_Name + ',''"'','''')'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLENAME
and data_Type in ('varchar')
```