# Remove Quotation Marks On All Rows in a Column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column in a table that has values encapsulated in quotation marks (i.e. "USA", "Mexico", "Russia", "China", etc.) I would like to remove the quotation marks and leave the rest of the string intact (USA, Mexico, etc.). Is there a simple statement for this?  Or do I need to use a combination of LEFT, RIGHT, and SUBSTRING functions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure it starts and ends " or do you need to test for it?

Comment: All values have "" around them. I need to remove them. I have tried to use a combination of LEFT, RIGHT, CHARINDEX, and SUBSTRING but I feel it's the wrong approach. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will remove all the `"` marks, even those in the middle of the value.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET CountryName = REPLACE(CountryName, '"', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to get rid of all double quotes, how about:

```
SELECT REPLACE(countryColumn, '"', '') AS countryColumn
FROM   theTable
```

Or a similar update if you actually want to modify the data.